# getJSON callback not happening

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, getjson

I have looked at similar queries here, but I can't seem to apply them to my problem. I am pretty new to jquery, so I may be doing something dumb.
I have a simple getJSON test:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".testurl").click(function() {
   // do a json call
   var url="testjson.php";
   var rc=$.getJSON(
    url,
    {parm1: "P1", parm2: "P2", parm3: "P3"},
    function(data){
     alert("callback function inline");
   });
   var x = 1;
  });
 });
```

that calls a really simple script:

```
  header("Content-Type: application/json");
  echo "{\"results\": [";
  $arr = array();
  $arr[] = "{\"fld1\": \"result1\", \"fld2\": \"result2\", \"fld3\": \"result3\"}";
  echo implode(", ", $arr);
  echo "]}";
```

that returns *valid*  JSON (I checked on JSON lint)

The var rc that I use to receive the result of the request has the following values:

```
getResponseText \"{\"results\": [{\"fld1\": \"result1\", \"fld2\": \"result2\", \"fld3\": \"result3\"}]}\"" 
getReadyState 4
getStatus 200
```

Why does the callback function not fire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the click handler is attached to an anchor element then maybe the ajax call doesn't have time to execute before redirecting to a different page. Try adding a `return false` to the click callback:

```
$(".testurl").click(function() {
    // do a json call
    // ...
    return false;
});
```

Comment: the anchor element has a href of #, so it stays on the page. I'm only attaching to that element as a really basic test page for trying this JSON stuff.

Comment: It was that - I added return false, and the callback triggered. How very odd - I'd have thought an anchor link would have let the call complete.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The $.getJSON call is just assigned to a variable, it is not being called.

Comment: I assigned it to a variable just to see what the results were. When I remove the assignment, the function still does not trigger.